# returns a fatal error : Index out of range when executing the function getBArrayList()

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

```
func getBArrayList(index: Int, array:[NSDictionary] ) -> [ 
NSDictionary]{
        var barray:[NSDictionary] = []
        for i in 0 ..< array.count
        {
           if array[i] == array[index]
            {
                break
            }

            barray[i] = array[i]


        }
        print(barray)
        return barray
    }

 minuscurent = getBArrayList(index: arrayindex, array: minuscurent)
```

when array[i ] equals array[index] i want to break the execution of the for loop and carry on with next value

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: side note: Dont use NS classes in Swift unless you have to. Use Dictionary or Array instead of NSDictionary and NSArray

Comment: @ReinierMelian i am trying to eliminate the content of the array with specific index,the array is an elemental array of type dictinary

Comment: @vishnu checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`barray` is initialized as an empty array, having no elements. On line:

```
barray[i] = array[i]
```

You are trying to access its `i`th element, but there are no elements in the array. That's the reason of the crash.

Use following to add those elements to `barray`:

```
barray.append(array[i])
```

Moreover, I believe it is enough to test the equality using:

```
if i == index
```

instead of:

```
if array[i] == array[index]
```

**UPDATE**

Now I am not 100% sure what you try to achieve, but it seems that you are just trying to remove all the elements after index `arrayindex` from the `minuscurent`.

```
minuscurent = getBArrayList(index: arrayindex, array: minuscurent)
```

If that is really the case, you don't have to implement your own implementation, and you can just use:

```
minuscurrent = minuscurrent.prefix(arrayindex)
```

If the goal is to remove just one element, again, use the standard implementation:

```
minuscurrent.remove(at: arrayindex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign object of NSDictionary directly into the array, if it is not initialised or in other words, if you have not provided the memory to the array.

> You should practise to use **barray.append(array[i])** instead of directly assigning the object to array.

- And, instead initialising the empty barray, you can use this so to always start with 0 index, instead 0 will be occupied by empty data.

  ```
   var barray = [NSDictionary]()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, i think there is no require for loop you can use ArraySlice https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice

```
func getBArrayList(index: Int, array:[NSDictionary] ) -> [NSDictionary] {
      var barray:[NSDictionary] = []
      if index >= 0 && index < array.count {
          barray.append(contentsOf: array[0..<index])
      }
      return barray
}
```

Comment: this does not do the same thing as his implementation

Comment: @vishnu checkout my answer